# VBA Plot of box and whiskers chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate plotting of a box and whiskers chart. The code below compiles and runs but the error bars do not appear in the chart.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim datarange As Range
Dim chtChart As Chart
Dim objChrt As ChartObject

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
Set datarange = ws.Range("F8:G10")

Set chtChart = Charts.add

With chtChart

  chtChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
  chtChart.SetSourceData Source:=datarange, PlotBy:=xlColumns

  With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        .CategoryNames = ws.Range("A2:A13")
        .TickLabels.Font.Bold = True
  End With
      .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
      .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue


    Dim Sec1 As Series
    Set Sec1 = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(3).HasErrorBars = True
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars.EndStyle = xlCap
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Transparency = 0
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBars.Format.Line.Weight = 1.5
    .SeriesCollection(3).ErrorBar Direction:=xlX, Include:=xlErrorBarIncludeBoth, Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, Amount:="=CHART!F12:G12", MinusValues:="=CHART!F12:G12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
    .SeriesCollection(3).values= <data range for whisker length>
```

type variant, data values required to plot whiskers
IMPORTANT: this overwrites the series collection values (seriescollection(3) in this case)
values can be replaced after plotting whiskers